# OrientDB: Is it possible to create a vertex together with an edge in one command?

Tags: orientdb

I've got three classes:

- Users extends V
- Links extends V
- Edges extends E

I have 3 Users, that won't usually change.

I have potentially 10000's of Links, and each one is connected to at least one of the Users (usually only one) via an Edge.

Is it possible to join these two commands, which are always called in succession, into one?

```
link = "insert into Links set title='Link 1'"
"create edge Edges
   from ( select from Users where user_id='"+user_id+"')
   to   ( select from " + link._rid + ")"
```

That is some kind of pseudocode, I'm checking this out with `pyorient`.

Comment: Just a couple of other pointers with your code.
1) Rather than having a separate user_id field, why not just use the rid as the id. It is far more performant to get a record via rid, rather than querying by field (which requires the database to open all records and check their field).
2) Instead of `"to   ( select from " + link._rid + ")"`, you can just do `"to " + link._rid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SQL Batch](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-batch.html).

Your command(s) might look like the following...

```
pyorient_client.batch("""begin
    let link = create vertex Links set name = 'Link 1'
    let user = select from Users where user_id = '{}' lock record
    let edge = create edge Edges from $user to $link
    commit
    return $edge""".format(user_id)
)
```